# To create a clone of tiny MCE in jQuery clone

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have to create a clone of a form, which i have made like the bellow.

```
        <div id="form-field" class="form">
            <input type="text" name="coursename" id="firstname" value="coursename" />
            <input type="text" name="institutename" id="institutename" value="institutename" />
            <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" value="startdate" />
            <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" value="enddate" />
            <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
            <label for="education-info">Educational Information</label>              
        </div>      
        <!-- clearfix -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- /clearfix -->
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
```

Now i use the jquery written bellow to create a clone of the above form. But i cant get the tiny MCE editor. How can i get the full tiny MCE editor.

My jQuery for clone of the form.

```
  jQuery('.addeducation-sym').click( function(){
    jQuery('#form-field').clone().appendTo('#form-field');
  });
```

Comment: You need to initialize the TinyMCE. Show us how you are doing it at the moment

Answer (score 1):

If you try to copy a form with an already initialized tinymce you will fail.

In case you are initializing tinymce after copying the form you need to make sure that the html element you get the editor for has a unique id. This id will be used as editor id and it comes to an error if you try to initialize two editors with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

If the base element (textarea, for example) has an ID on it and this gets cloned too then you have two elements with the same ID. Not allowed in HTML and also as tinymce takes it's instance ID from the element ID by default the clone doesn't really work.

The trick is to remove the editors first with

```
tinymce.remove();
```

Then clone your elements with jquery.

Before writing your cloned elements to the DOM you need to rename the IDs of any cloned elements to have unique IDs.

Then write the clone to the DOM, then call

```
tinymce.init(TINYMCE_SETTINGS);
```

where TINYMCE_SETTINGS is an object of all your settings in.